# How to display 'A & B' instead of 'A &amp; B' in NextJs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to display `'A & B'` but NextJs is displaying it as `A &amp; B` as the original string from the API. Could anyone of you please let me know how I could update `'&amp;' or other symbols` to their original form instead of code?

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to show more context of where the string is coming from and what you are doing with it to display it.

Comment: General thought is that your API should not be returning encoded data or at the very least you need to decode it when you get it? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React escapes html entities. You can explicitly disable it via [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) if you want to emit raw html, but you ***should not do this unless you are 100% certain that the html will never contain malicious code***. If it's possible that it will contain user input, for example ***do not do this*** or you're subjecting yourself to security vulnerabilities.

The snippet below uses `React.createElement` because I still haven't figured out how to get JSX to work in SO snippets, but it's the equivalent of:

```
<div>{text}</div>
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: text}}></div>
```

```js
const text = "A &amp; B";

const unescaped = React.createElement('div', {}, text);
const escaped = React.createElement('div', { dangerouslySetInnerHTML: { __html: text} })

ReactDOM.render(unescaped, document.getElementById('a'));
ReactDOM.render(escaped, document.getElementById('b'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

Comment: Probably better to manually decode the string first than to opt out of React's sanitization algorithm.

Comment: I achieved what I want with `<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: variable }}></p>`